# I am not able to insert data into my sqlite db.. I don't have any error showing up but the values are not inserting into the db

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Here is my code that I have written..

```
NSArray *path= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docpath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
dbpathstring = [docpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserTable.db"];
char *error,*error1;

NSFileManager *filemanager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![filemanager fileExistsAtPath:dbpathstring])
{
    const char *dbpath=[dbpathstring UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &userdb1)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql_stat= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERTABLE (CARDNUMBER INTEGER,BALANCE INTEGER,DATE TEXT)";
        sqlite3_exec(userdb1, sql_stat, NULL, NULL, &error);
        sqlite3_close(userdb1);

    }
}


if(sqlite3_open([dbpathstring UTF8String], &userdb1)==SQLITE_OK)
{


    NSString *insertstmnt= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO USERTABLE (CARDNUMBER,BALANCE,DATE) VALUES((\"%d\", \"%d\", \"%s\")",[crd1 intValue],[bal1 intValue],[rdt1 UTF8String]];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertstmnt UTF8String];


    sqlite3_exec(userdb1, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error1);

        NSLog(@"After Creation in insert exec");

        NSLog(@"row added");
        UserTables *usertable = [[UserTables alloc]init];
        [usertable setCardnumber:[crd1 intValue]];
        [usertable setBalance:[bal1 intValue]];
        [usertable setDate:rdt1];
        [sections addObject:usertable];


    sqlite3_close(userdb1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `(` in your `INSERT` query, causing a syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO USERTABLE (CARDNUMBER,BALANCE,DATE) VALUES((\"%d\", \"%d\", \"%s\")
```

change to

```
INSERT INTO USERTABLE (CARDNUMBER,BALANCE,DATE) VALUES(\"%d\", \"%d\", \"%s\")
```